# Relation between $L^2(\mathbb{R}_+)$ and $L^1_w(\mathbb{R}_+)$

Tags: analysis, lp-spaces

As an exercice, I'm looking to find an inclusion or equality relationship between $L^2(\mathbb{R}_+)$ and $L^1_w(\mathbb{R}_+)$ when $w: x \to x^{-1/2}$.

Actually, I think that we have the inclusion $L^2(\mathbb{R}_+) \subset L^1_w(\mathbb{R}_+)$ but I am not able to prove it.

Could someone of you got a hint?

Comment: What is the $L_w^1(\mathbb{R}_+)$ space exactly?

Comment: $L^1_w(\mathbb{R}_+)= \{ f : \int_0^{+\infty} \vert f(x) \vert w(x) dx < \infty \}= \{ f : \int_0^{+\infty} \vert f(x) \vert x^{-1/2} dx < \infty \}$

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion $L^2\subset L^1_w$ does not hold: take $f(x):=\frac 1{\sqrt x\log x}\chi_{(1,\infty)}(x)$.

The converse reduces to ask whether $g\in L^1$ implies $x\mapsto xg(x)^2\in L^1$. Define 
$$g(x):=\sum_{j=1}^\infty c_j\cdot\chi(j^2-a_j,j^2+a_j)(x),$$
with the $a_j$ small enough.
Then $g$ is integrable if and only if $\sum_{j=1}^\infty c_ja_j$ is convergent
and $x\mapsto xg(x)^2\in L^1$ if and only if $\sum_{l=1}^\infty a_j j^2c_j^2$ is convergent.